# How to open a Web Console for open shift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise, openshift-3

guys I am using OpenShift to conatinerize and run application on kubernetes,  I have started the open shift cluster using `oc cluster up` now how do I open in the web console.
For the mini shift I have user `minishift start` and then `minishift console` it's not working the same with `oc cluster up`

Comment: For ``oc cluster up`` when you run ``oc login`` it should show you the URL you can use. You can also get it using ``oc whoami --show-server``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `oc whoami --show-console` returns the link to the console app.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the console URL in OpenShift Container Platform 4 as follows:

```
$ oc get routes -n openshift-console
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, `oc login` helped me to get the web console url